# nth Child Even and Odd for IE 7 + 8

Tags: javascript, html, css

Without resorting to using jQuery, how could one find a replacement function in Javascript or CSS to simulate the css:

```
table#report tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#eeeeee; }

table#report tr:nth-child(even){ background-color:#ffffff; }
```

I am at a loss and have to find a work around for the above.

Comment: You could use some script to set the classes (by iterating orver the rows).

Comment: This could be tough specifically if you are manipulating the rows somewhat often, like moving them around or adding/removing some - but at the same time, you could make a function and call it every time you modify the collection (just isn't the most efficient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using javascript and css clases:

JS:

```
var children = document.getElementById('report').getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i=0, len=children.length; i<len; i++) {
  var child = children[i];
  if (i%2 === 0) {
    child.className += " even";
  } else {
    child.className += " odd";
  }
}​
```

css:

```
table#report tr.even {
    background: #F00; /*or the color of your choice*/
}

table#report tr.odd {
    background: #00F; /*or the color of your choice*/
}
```

​
And a jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rNTH8/2/

Comment: I like this variation of it, because of the choice to define the classes of css. Way to go! Appreciate everyone's hard work.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I did this and it work just fine

```
var aTr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for(var i=0, ii=aTr.length; i<ii; i++){
    if(i%2!=0){
        aTr[i].style.backgroundColor = "#eeeeee";
    }else{aTr[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";}
}
```

Comment: Adding a class name should be preferred to directly applying an inline style.

Comment: +1, or add a class instead of setting individual styles. Perhaps more maintainable, but same concept.

Comment: This would probably be used with `table.tBodies` to not apply this to the `<thead>` section.

Comment: @Ian well, this help how Jason want to do it, the Idea is there.

Comment: I mean the formatting (like spaces, tabs) in your code example. The indenting was messed up. I fixed it but you changed it again (maybe it was an accident)

Comment: Haaaaaaaa no usualy it is better,, I do not know why it appeard like that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that basic JavaScript is okay, for a functional approach I'd suggest:

```
function oddEven(table) {
    if (!table) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        table = table.nodeType == 1 ? table : document.getElementById(table);
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        for (var i=0, len=rows.length; i<len; i++) {
            rows[i].className = i%2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
        }
    }
}

oddEven('tableID');
oddEven(document.getElementById('tableID'));
```

[JS Fiddle demo: `oddEven('tableID');`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Tb87q/).

[JS Fiddle demo: `oddEven(document.getElementByID('tableID'));`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Tb87q/1/).

Revised the above function to only apply to the rows in the `tbody`:

```
function oddEven(table) {
    if (!table) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        table = table.nodeType == 1 ? table : document.getElementById(table);
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody').length ? table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr') : table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        for (var i=0, len=rows.length; i<len; i++) {
            rows[i].className = i%2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
        }
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo: `oddEven('tableID');`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Tb87q/3/).

[JS Fiddle demo: `oddEven(document.getElementByID('tableID'));`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Tb87q/2/).

Answer (score 0):

The work-around is to use alternating class names on the output. You can apply these at run-time using jQuery if you don't want to change your mark-up server-side.

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery this can be done without problems

Just like that:

```
$('#report tr:nth-child(2n+1)').addClass('odd');
```